# Sum of FSRM Quotas

Tags: powershell, sum, quota

I want to make a small script in PowerShell that could be able to tell me the real amount of storage remaining on my disk taking quotas into account.

I get the remaining storage disk this way :

`$RemainingSizeDisk = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -Property DeviceID,@{'Name' = 'FreeSpace (GB)'; Expression= {([math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace / 1GB), 2)) }} | Measure-Object -Property 'FreeSpace (GB)' -Sum).Sum`

I also get the various quotas thanks to this :

`Get-FsrmQuota | Format-Table Path, @{Label="Size_GB";  Expression = { ("{0:F2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)); $TotalQuotaSize += $_.Size }}`

The thing is, `$TotalQuotaSize` is empty even with multiple quotas existing.

Comment: I would bet that using format-table is the reason for that. Usually you should follow {Input | Process | Output} pipeline. And Format-Table is part of "Output" commands. I suggest you to replace it with Select-Object and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me !

`$Quotas = @(Get-FSRMQuota |Select-Object Size)`
`Foreach($Quota in $Quotas){ $Size = ($Quota.Size / 1GB) $TotalQuotaSize += $Size}`